# Sending a message to a certain user with TeleBot in telegram

Tags: telebot

How should I send a message to a certain member of the robot?

I tried with @RawDataBot robot bot it just passes the chat id of two users in telegram and I can't get the message from the robot to forward it to the @RawDataBot robot

Comment: Please add the code you are trying to run. Which programming language do you use? Which telegram api module? What error do you get?